# c# jquery and webservices access

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services

My .NET solution uses jQuery and webservices for ajax. I'm looking for a way to restrict the access to the webservices only for my own domain. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this [**link**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) might be helpful you can specify the request origin as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="YOUR_SERVICE_NAME">
        <domain uri="http://YOUR_DOMAIN.com"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

A web service is the same as any other HTTP-based resource, e.g. network rules (such as on a firewall) can be applied. If your web service was created as a WCF endpoint, you have granular security controls available to you, including claims-based authentication where the originating domain can be a claim.